# How to create a laravel hashed password

Tags: php, security, laravel, hash, passwords

I am trying to create an hashed password for Laravel. Now someone told me to use Laravel hash helper but I can't seem to find it or I'm looking in the wrong direction.

How do I create a laravel hashed password? And where?

Edit:
I know what the code is but I don't know where and how to use it so it gives me back the hashed password. If I get the hashed password then I can manually insert it into the database

Comment: Check how to [make Hash and Verify Hash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33740080/1045444) in Laravel.

Comment: For those of you who are here to just manually create a hashed password, you can use the answer below with `php artisan tinker`. E.g., `echo Hash::make('yourpassword')`

Comment: The quickest manual method which is helpful in the command line environment:

`php artisan tinker` then `bcrypt("yourpassword")`

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Hashing A Password Using Bcrypt in `Laravel`:

```
$password = Hash::make('yourpassword');
```

This will create a hashed password. You may use it in your controller or even in a model, for example, if a user submits a password using a form to your controller using `POST` method then you may hash it using something like this:

```
$password = Input::get('passwordformfield'); // password is form field
$hashed = Hash::make($password);
```

Here, `$hashed` will contain the hashed password. Basically, you'll do it when creating/registering a new user, so, for example, if a user submits details such as, `name`, `email`, `username` and `password` etc using a form, then before you insert the data into database, you'll hash the password after validating the data. For more information, [read the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/hashing).

**Update:**

```
$password = 'JohnDoe';
$hashedPassword = Hash::make($password);
echo $hashedPassword; // $2y$10$jSAr/RwmjhwioDlJErOk9OQEO7huLz9O6Iuf/udyGbHPiTNuB3Iuy
```

So, you'll insert the `$hashedPassword` into database. Hope, it's clear now and if still you are confused then i suggest you to read some tutorials, watch some screen casts on [laracasts.com](http://laracasts.com) and [tutsplus.com](http://tutsplus.com/) and also read a book on `Laravel`, [this is a free ebook](http://www.thebook-mark.com/laravel-code-bright/), you may download it.

**Update:** Since `OP` wants to manually encrypt password using Laravel `Hash` without any class or form so this is an alternative way using `artisan tinker` from command prompt:

1. Go to your command prompt/terminal
2. Navigate to the `Laravel` installation (your project's root directory)
3. Use `cd <directory name>` and press enter from command prompt/terminal
4. Then write `php artisan tinker` and press enter
5. Then write `echo Hash::make('somestring');`
6. You'll get a hashed password on the console, copy it and then do whatever you want to do.

### Update (Laravel 5.x):

```
// Also one can use bcrypt
$password = bcrypt('JohnDoe');
```

---

Comment: But where should i do this. I came across this a few times.

Comment: I think i made a wrong question. My database(which i got from someone else) has only hashed passwords for users. Now i want to create an password which should be hashed by laravel. How can i create an hashed password so i can enter this in the db.

Comment: That is what I've answered, to save a password into `db` you need to encrypt it so, from a plain password you'll encrypt it using `Hash::make('passwordstring');` and then save this hashed password in the database.

Comment: But how do i do this? If i just for example create a php file this doesn't work. As you'll understand i'm quite new to laravel

Comment: I think i still have a misleading question. Because I understand what you are saying. But where should I use this code? In which file or ... ? Because i'm only going to use this once. It's not for somekind of form that i can add a user or something.

Comment: Please describe what exactly you are going to do, in easy non-confusing words or phrases.

Comment: I have a table users where i can add another user. All the passwords are hashed by laravel. How can i get my password hashed so than i can enter it in my db.

I know i must use Hash::make(myPassword) but how can i use it? I i just create a php file in my laravel project and run it it doesn't work. So where can i use it to get my password hashed

Comment: Do you want to manually hash passwords one by one and then you want to save each one manually in database ?

Comment: Yes. I just want to add 1 user and then manually add this in the database? or is this not possible?

Comment: What is your `OS`, anyways, check the updated answer.

Comment: Let me know the result soon, I'll leave now.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i needed. Would like to give a plus 1 but i don't have enough rep

Comment: You are welcome and it's `OK` I got the reputation from you because you said it and it's enough and +1 to your question as well :-)

Comment: For those of you using Laravel 5.0, for some reason, if you update the password using `php artisan tinker` approach, it automatically hashes it for you, so you need to do this: `> $u1->password = 'plaintextpassword'; $u1->save(); ` instead of `$u1->password = Hash::make('plaintextpassword'); $u1->save();`. I don't know why but that's the way it happens. Wasted a half hour wondering why my password changes didn't work. Turns out, they were pre-hashed.

Comment: @TheAlpha hi sir, could you help me on this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771638/laravel-updateorcreate-on-onetoone-relationship  Thanks

Answer (score 27):

I know your pain bro. You just need the password Hash to replace the password column field in the database. You can get it easily from laravel tinker.
On any laravel project command line type:

```
❯ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.12 (PHP 7.4.27 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> echo Hash::make('123456');
$2y$10$JHK.2MTc9ORMmmlqoF.gg.SwDLnevVSj1oreHParu5PvcPEDOWqe6
```

then copy the hashed pass for your use case.

Answer (score 22):

The Laravel Hash facade provides secure Bcrypt hashing for storing user passwords.

Basic usage required two things:

First include the Facade in your file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

and use `Make` Method to generate password.

```
$hashedPassword = Hash::make($request->newPassword);
```

and when you want to match the Hashed string you can use the below code:

```
Hash::check($request->newPasswordAtLogin, $hashedPassword)
```

You can learn more with the Laravel document link below for Hashing:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing

Answer (score 19):

Laravel 5 uses `bcrypt`. So, you can do this as well.

```
$hashedpassword = bcrypt('plaintextpassword');
```

output of which you can save to your database table's password field.

Fn Ref: [bcrypt](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-bcrypt)

Comment: Where do you get this function from, it isn't part of PHP or Laravel is it?

Comment: @martinstoeckli Oh it is, it is a helper function in L5, http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing#basic-usage

Comment: Looks like it was introduced in the recent Laravel 5.1 http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-bcrypt

Comment: How to decrypt this? IS there helper for this too?

Comment: @Fusion bcrypt is a hashing algorithm, not an encryption algorithm, with hashing you can't get back the plain text once the hash is generated for it. This is the whole point of hashing algorithm. Only thing you can do is check if a plain text matches with the hash you have.

Comment: @Fusion More on this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18084693/1161412
 Diff b/w the two: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4948393/1161412

Comment: thanks for answer, i just check in database like this  ->where('password', '=',bcrypt($request->input('password')))

doesn't work

Comment: @FreddySidauruk That won't work because bcrypt generates different hash every time, even if the input password is same. You will have to use the `check` method: `if (Hash::check('secret', $hashedPassword)) { // The passwords match... }` Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/hashing Edit: Don't forget to upvote the answer if it has helped you ;)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to understand how excatly laravel works you  can review the complete class on Github: https://github.com/illuminate/hashing/blob/master/BcryptHasher.php

But basically there are Three PHP methods involved on that:

```
$pasword = 'user-password';
// To create a valid password out of laravel Try out!
$cost=10; // Default cost
$password = password_hash($pasword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => $cost]);

// To validate the password you can use
$hash = '$2y$10$NhRNj6QF.Bo6ePSRsClYD.4zHFyoQr/WOdcESjIuRsluN1DvzqSHm';

if (password_verify($pasword, $hash)) {
   echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
   echo 'Invalid password.';
}

//Finally if you have a $hash but you want to know the information about that hash. 
print_r( password_get_info( $password_hash ));
```

The hashed password is same as laravel 5.x bcrypt password. No need to give salt and cost, it will take its default values.

Those methods has been implemented in the laravel class, but if you want to learn more please review the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Works. Can be used to reset password if only database access is available.

Answer (score 9):

## To store password in database, make hash of password and then save.

```
$password = Input::get('password_from_user'); 
$hashed = Hash::make($password); // save $hashed value
```

## To verify password, get password stored of account from database

```
// $user is database object
// $inputs is Input from user
if( \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::check( $inputs['password'], $user['password']) == false) {
  // Password is not matching 
} else {
  // Password is matching 
}
```

Comment: I love this answer because it tells where Hash located ( Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;    
$password = request('password'); // get the value of password field
$hashed = Hash::make($password); // encrypt the password
```

N.B: Use 1st line code at the very beginning in your controller. Last but not the least, use the rest two lines of code inside the function of your controller where you want to manipulate with data after the from is submitted. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
$hashed_password = Hash::make('Your Unhashed Password');
```

You can find more information: [here](http://laravel.com/docs/security)

Answer (score 2):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

You can use to hashing password =>    Hash::make('yourpassword');

You can use checking password =>   Hash::check($password, $user->password);

Answer (score 1):

In the BcryptHasher.php you can find the hash code:

```
public function make($value, array $options = array())
{
    $cost = isset($options['rounds']) ? $options['rounds'] : $this->rounds;

    $hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => $cost));

            $hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => $cost));
            echo $value.' '.PASSWORD_BCRYPT.' '.$cost.' ';
            echo $hash;die();
    if ($hash === false)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Bcrypt hashing not supported.");
    }

    return $hash;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
if(Hash::check($plain-text,$hashed-text))
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

eg-
$plain-text = 'text';
$hashed-text=Hash::make('text');

Comment: Yes. This is the right way. Need to use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Create a function

```
    
    public function bcryptGenerator($password)
    {
        return \bcrypt($password);
    }
```

### Call the function

```
bcryptGenerator(123456);
// password = 123456
```

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer with much better explanation than yours.

Comment: Why wrap the function in another function? This is a nonsense answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Compare password in laravel and lumen:**

This may be possible that bcrypt function does not work with php7 then you can use below code in laravel and lumen as per your requirements:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

$test = app('hash')->make("test");
if (Hash::check('test', $test)) {
   echo "matched";
} else {
   echo "no matched";
}
```

I hope, this help will make you happy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $data->password = Hash::make(($request->password));  //Password 
  Encripted  

//Login code

if ($data = AddEmployee::where('name', $request->name)->first()) {
        $pass = Hash::check($request->password, $data->password);
        if ($pass) {
            echo "sucess";
        } else {
            echo "Password Not Valid";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Username Not Valid" . "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Controller which is used to insert the password, just use 'use Hash;'.

Answer (score -6):

ok, this is a extract from the make function in hash.php

```
    $work = str_pad(8, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    // Bcrypt expects the salt to be 22 base64 encoded characters including
    // dots and slashes. We will get rid of the plus signs included in the
    // base64 data and replace them with dots.
    if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes'))
    {
        $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    }
    else
    {
        $salt = Str::random(40);
    }

    $salt = substr(strtr(base64_encode($salt), '+', '.'), 0 , 22);

    echo crypt('yourpassword', '$2a$'.$work.'$'.$salt);
```

Just copy/paste it into a php file and run it.

Comment: This is REALLY bad practice. Unless you're very proficient in cryptography, you should simply use the built in already made hashing functions.