# Laravel updateOrCreate on OneToOne relationShip

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

in my web application i have this models:

```
InstagramAccount.php 
UserPageFeed.php
```

each InstagramAccount has one record into UserPageFeed and each UserPageFeed  belongs to one record into InstagramAccount, then that's `one to one` relationship,

**PROBLEM:**

> my below code couldn't update existing row on table and create again

```
$userSelectedPage = InstagramAccount::whereUsername('my_page')->first();
$userPageFeeds = new UserPageFeed();
$userSelectedPage->account()->updateOrCreate([
    'instagram_account_id' => $userPageFeeds->id, //exsiting row
    'page_name' => 'test',
    'feeds' => 'test',
    'cache_time' => Carbon::now()->addHour(6),
]);
```

or this code:

```
$userSelectedPage = InstagramAccount::whereUsername('content.world')->first();
$salam = $userSelectedPage->account()->updateOrCreate([
    'instagram_account_id' => $userSelectedPage->id,
    'page_name' => 'aaaaaaa',
    'feeds' => 'ddd',
    'cache_time' => Carbon::now()->addHour(6),
]);
```

user_page_feeds table structure:

```
id                     ->Primary
instagram_account_id   ->Index
feeds
page_name
cache_time
created_at
updated_at
```

with this index:

```
"Keyname":user_page_feeds_instagram_account_id_foreign  "Column":instagram_account_id
```

instagram_accounts table structure:

```
id                     ->Primary
user_id                ->Index
uid
fid
proxy
avatar
username
password
checkpoint
account_data
people_data
status
created_at
updated_at
```

`InstagramAccount` model:

```
class InstagramAccount extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $casts = [
        'account_data' => 'array',
        'people_data' => 'array'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function account()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserPageFeed::class);
    }
}
```

`UserPageFeed` model:

```
class UserPageFeed extends Model
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $casts = [
        'feeds' => 'array'
    ];

    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(InstagramAccount::class,'instagram_account_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: you have wrong casts,no instagram_account_id,what error are you getting

Comment: @Eminem, i dont get any arror

Comment: @DolDurma, Seems, it has been resolved :-)

Comment: @TheAlpha Hi sir, yes thanks to view my problem in this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `updateOrCreate()` with two separate parameters:

```php
$userSelectedPage->account()->updateOrCreate(
    ['instagram_account_id' => $userPageFeeds->id],
    [
        'page_name' => 'test',
        'feeds' => 'test',
        'cache_time' => Carbon::now()->addHour(6),
    ]
);
```

The first parameter contains the attributes that Laravel uses to find the existing 
`account`.
The second parameter contains the attributes that Laravel uses to create or update the `account`.

Comment: I tested that before posting problem, but it work fine now :)