# how to make a password hash laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

```
// method untuk insert data ke table d_rak
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data=new User();
        $data->name=$request->get('name');
        $data->username=$request->get('username');
        $data->nip=$request->get('nip');
        $data->level=$request->get('level');
        $data->email=$request->get('email');
        $data->password=$request->get('password');
        $data->save();

    return redirect ('/users')->with('alert-success','Berhasil Menambahkan Data!');

    }
```

Comment: Hash::make($request->get('password'))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a laravel hashed password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846897/how-to-create-a-laravel-hashed-password)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

```
$data->password= Hash::make($request->get('password'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `bcrypt` helper.

```
$data->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
```

or `Hash` facade.

```
$data->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**For use in controller:**

```
$request->user()->fill([
            'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)
        ])->save();
```

**And check if is the correct password**

The check method allows you to verify that a given plain-text string corresponds to a given hash. However, if you are using the LoginController included with Laravel, you will probably not need to use this directly, as this controller automatically calls this method:

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```