# Data type of 'password' field for manual input in phpmyadmin for Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-authentication

In my Laravel application I have two type of Users. One is 'Admin' and another is 'Users'.

For Admin I want to input an 'username' and 'password' manually to the database. So what's the data type of the 'password' field of 'users' table for manual input ?

I have tried with 'SHA1'. But while I trying to login for that 'Admin' it gives error.

**controller login**

```
public function admin_login(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $request->validate([
        'username'     => 'required',
        'password'  => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($validator)) {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

**phpmyadmin**
[image]

Anybody help please ? Thanks in advance ?

Comment: Create a pasword hashed with Hash::make('yourpassword') and use this response

Comment: This is duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/22846971/13112515

Comment: Your paremeter un attempt is wrong. Use something like $credentials = array('username' => request->username, 'password' =>request->password);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a laravel hashed password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846897/how-to-create-a-laravel-hashed-password)

Comment: @ShaiCohen...that is a part of my question's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let me clear one thing here is that Larvel uses Hash "bcrypt", "argon", "argon2id" driver to hashing the string. That is specific to the programming language, not the database language.

You could run

`php artisan tinker`

in your console and after.

```
echo Hash::make('admin_password_whatever_you_like')
```

You will get the string and copy this string and save it into the database without calling any MySQL method.

Comment: ....yes I have got a hashed password using your code. And paste it in my database. But still isn't login !!
And suppose my password is 'test'. so I use `echo Hash::make('test')`
For every time refresh my browser I have got different password.

Comment: This is the "bcrypt" type hashing which is always generating new string. and your attempt of Auth is not correct I think. It should be something like
if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            echo "show error here";
        } else {
            // good to go.
        }