# Which method is used in laravel/fortify password hash?

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

Reading https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify (laravel 8) I did not find with which method password
is created on register?
When I created user in migration with bcrypt method it does not work with

```
Hash::check
```

method?

In other words which method have I to use migration adding user?

Thanks!

Comment: Pls post the code you are using for seeding the data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a laravel hashed password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846897/how-to-create-a-laravel-hashed-password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is using `Hash::make($input['password'])`. You can find it in `app\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser.php`.