# Laravel hashed password

Tags: php, sql, laravel

How to make a hashed authentication? so  made this login function for my project, and my teacher asked me to make this login with hash and bcrypt, but I have no idea about that

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $kredensil = $request->only('username', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($kredensil)) {

        $users = Auth::user();

        if($users->level == 'admin'){

            return redirect()->intended('admin/siswa');
            
        }

        elseif ($users->level == 'siswa') {

            return redirect()->intended('siswa/home');

        }

        return redirect('login')->with('error', 'Login gagal harap cek username dan password');
    }
    return redirect('login')->with('error', 'Login gagal harap cek username dan password');
}
```

Comment: Auth::attempt(), In this method laravel handles authenciation.

Comment: What are you trying to say by hashed authentication? what you want to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a laravel hashed password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846897/how-to-create-a-laravel-hashed-password)

Answer (score 0):

Hashing algorithm can be changed via `config/hashing.php`.

```php
'driver' => 'bcrypt'
```

When a user registers, the password is usually hashed by using `Hash::make()`. Most of the authentication packages does this by default.

`Auth::attempt()` hashes the given password behind the scene and compare it to the hashed one in the database.