# Change the Hash password in laravel using Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, laravel

I use `Hash::make($req->pass);` to login in Laravel. Now I forgot the password. Can I change the password by editing PHPMyAdmin? Is there any PHPMyadmin function to change the Bcrypt?

For eg. To change the password stored in MD5, I can change it by using MD5 function. And it works fine for all WordPress logins.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a laravel hashed password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846897/how-to-create-a-laravel-hashed-password)

Comment: I already create it, but I want to update a password that is already created using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Yes, that code shows you how to manually run `Hash::make()`, the output of which you can manually enter into the database

Comment: "_To change the password stored in MD5 ..._" Unrelated info: From PHP's [md5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) manual: "_Warning It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See the [Password Hashing FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) for details and best practices._"

Comment: You can use the artisan console to change the password

Answer (score 1):

I would use Tinker to achieve this:

```bash
php artisan tinker

$user = App/Models/User()::find(/* user_id */);

$user->password = Hash::make('your new password here');

$user->save();

// You should receive a "true" if the update is successful. 
// This can all be done via the command line.
```

You can also (for the sake of answering your question) just output the password from the route file:

```php
Route::get('generate-password', function () {
  return Hash::make('your new password');
})
```

visit the '/generate-password' url, copy that password, then paste it into PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

One way to change the password manually is to get the value from

```
$pw=Hash::make('yourpassword');
```

to a variable and copy that value into users table password field.