# How to login with phone number and country code in Laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I have a login page with email id and password . Now  in the API I received country code and  phone number along with the password.
My code is below.

```
        if(!isset($request->phone)){
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember_me' => 'boolean',
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    } else {
        $request->validate([
            'phone' => 'required|string',
            'country_code' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember_me' => 'boolean',
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['phone', 'country_code', 'password']);

    }
    if(isset($request->phone)){
        $user = User::where('phone',$credentials['phone'])->where('country_code',$credentials['country_code'])->first();
        if(!Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->password)){
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);            
        }
    } else {
        if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        }
        $user = $request->user();
    }
    return $user->only(['id', 'name', 'email', 'api_token']);
```

How do I login with phone number and country code? And also Where does the Auth:attempt resides so that I can copy it and use it in same fashion

Comment: What are you asking? By “authenticate” are you asking how to set up 2fa?

Comment: I need to login with phone number and country code

Answer (score 1):

Check if the country code and phone number match, then retrieve the user details using that, after that run

```
Hash::check('INPUT PASSWORD', $user->password);
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25136309/8594737 for similar description, although it is a bit different, but similar concept.

Let me know if you need anything else, will do my best to reply.